# Derive text between p elements

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract for a bunch of downloaded files the text between P strong elements. 
I want all the P texts between the P strong "Executives" and P strong "Analysts", i attached an example of a html see [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6HK1.png)
I know how to load the htmls, but i don't know how to extract the data mentioned earlier with BS4:

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/test/out'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
```

Example of html:

```
</header><div id="a-cont"><div class="p p1"></div><div class="sa-art article-width" id="a-body"><p>Apple, Inc. (NASDAQ:<a href="https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL" title="Apple Inc.">AAPL</a>)</p>
<p>Q4 2016 Earnings Call</p>
<p>October 25, 2016 5:00 pm ET</p>
<p><strong>Executives</strong></p>
<p>Nancy Paxton - Apple, Inc.</p>
<p>Timothy Donald Cook - Apple, Inc.</p>
<p>Luca Maestri - Apple, Inc.</p>
<p><strong>Analysts</strong></p>
<p>Eugene Charles Munster - Piper Jaffray &amp; Co.</p>
<p>Kathryn Lynn Huberty - Morgan Stanley &amp; Co. LLC</p>
<p>Shannon S. Cross - Cross Research LLC</p>
<p>Antonio M. Sacconaghi - Sanford C. Bernstein &amp; Co. LLC</p>
<p>Simona K. Jankowski - Goldman Sachs &amp; Co.</p>
<p>Steven M. Milunovich - UBS Securities LLC</p>
<p>Wamsi Mohan - Bank of America Merrill Lynch</p>
<p>James D. Suva - Citigroup Global Markets, Inc. (Broker)</p>
<p>Rod B. Hall - JPMorgan Securities LLC</p>
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Can you share sample data of this 'html.parser' file?

Comment: Thank you @Sampath ! I updated my question with the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, a very rough solution could be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''
<div id="a-cont"><div class="p p1"></div><div class="sa-art article-width" id="a-body"><p>Apple, Inc. (NASDAQ:<a href="https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL" title="Apple Inc.">AAPL</a>)</p>
<p>Q4 2016 Earnings Call</p>
<p>October 25, 2016 5:00 pm ET</p>
<p><strong>Executives</strong></p>
<p>Nancy Paxton - Apple, Inc.</p>
<p>Timothy Donald Cook - Apple, Inc.</p>
<p>Luca Maestri - Apple, Inc.</p>
<p><strong>Analysts</strong></p>
<p>Eugene Charles Munster - Piper Jaffray &amp; Co.</p>
<p>Kathryn Lynn Huberty - Morgan Stanley &amp; Co. LLC</p>
<p>Shannon S. Cross - Cross Research LLC</p>
<p>Antonio M. Sacconaghi - Sanford C. Bernstein &amp; Co. LLC</p>
<p>Simona K. Jankowski - Goldman Sachs &amp; Co.</p>
<p>Steven M. Milunovich - UBS Securities LLC</p>
<p>Wamsi Mohan - Bank of America Merrill Lynch</p>
<p>James D. Suva - Citigroup Global Markets, Inc. (Broker)</p>
<p>Rod B. Hall - JPMorgan Securities LLC</p>
'''

bsobj = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")
res = []

for i in bsobj.find('strong').find_all_next('p'):
    if i.text == 'Analysts':
        break
    else:
        res.append(i.text)

res
```

and you get:

```
['Nancy Paxton - Apple, Inc.',
 'Timothy Donald Cook - Apple, Inc.',
 'Luca Maestri - Apple, Inc.']
```

---

After further explanation from the OP, the final code should be something like:

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = {}
directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/Transcripts/test/1/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')

            res[filename] = []
            for i in soup.find('strong').find_all_next('p'):
                if i.text == 'Analysts':
                    break
                else:
                    res[filename].append(i.text)
```

Comment: would this also work for files i already downloaded? (as mentioned in my question) and called by with the code " import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/test/out'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')"

Comment: As long as the object in `bsobj = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")` has a similar structure of the one in my code, I would say yes. Just try it. And if this answer solves your problem, please accept it!

Comment: i tried to merge my "directory load" with your approach, but this does not seem to work (in the question, i edited this merger i am talking about).

Comment: In your code, remove `bsobj = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "lxml")`, move my `for` loop inside the initial `for` loop, renaming `bsobj` into `soup`.

Comment: could you edit this in my question section ? (because i don't understand what you mean)

Comment: Sorry but i've got no output. I only see is "finished in 1,3 seconds"...

Comment: What is the outuput of `soup`? And the output of `res`?

Comment: I found the problem, tekst should be "Analysts:" Can i also print this in columns or rows? I will put this question on answered, thanks!!!